# 'Permission denied' when attempting to access mailbox

Tags: centos, sendmail, user-management

I created a new user through `useradd <username> -M` and added them to the `virtusertable` and `generic-domains` When I log into the new user though, when I try `mail`, I get the error `/var/spool/mail/<otheruser>: Permission denied`

What am I missing?

Thanks so much for the help

Comment: This is nothing to do with sendmail. Sendmail does not deal with mailboxes.

Comment: It does deal with mailboxes if there's no MDA configured, but it certainly doesn't _read_ from them.

Answer (score 4):

What are the permissions on `/var/spool/mail`?  It should probably be owner root, group mail, mode 1777. If that is in order, is there already a `/var/spool/mail/otheruser` mail file?  Is it owned by otheruser (`ls -la /var/spool/mail/otheruser`).

That message is telling you that either the permissions on `/var/spool/mail` or on `/var/spool/mail/otheruser` are wrong.

You mention you put entries in virtusertable and generic-domains, what did you put there?

You can check that mail is being delivered to that user by sending a message to that user from your original user and checking what `/var/spool/log/maillog` reports about the attempted delivery.